# Ruby on Rails: "couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.datepicker'"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

Okay, this is driving me nuts. I've been following the instructions to install a JQuery datepicker here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars-revised but I'm getting hung up on this error:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Verifications#new

couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.datepicker'
  (in /app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:11)
```

Here's application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Here's application.css:

```
 *= require jquery.ui.datepicker
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
```

and in Gemfile:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
end
```

Anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Answering my own question here in case someone else makes the same dumb mistake. I restarted the rails server, and then it worked.

Comment: I had the same error but for `bootstrap-datetimepicker`. Restarting the Rails server worked.

Comment: All other solutions failed for me - this was the ticket!

Answer (score 31):

For future readers. First, make sure you've restarted your rails server after installing the gem as krstck answered.

Then, double check the version of your gem. `jquery-ui-rails` has changed its `require` syntax in `5.0.0`. Now you should write:

```
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
```

Also add to css

```
*= require jquery-ui/datepicker
```

Comment: And *= require jquery-ui/datepicker to css

Answer (score 16):

For Rails 5 users, to use the `jQuery` datepicker you must add this to your `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/datepicker
```

And this to your `application.css`:

```
/*
 *= require jquery-ui/datepicker
 */
```

You can also just use the usual gem version:

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

Restart your server as well.

Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/jquery-ui-rails/jquery-ui-rails#require-specific-modules)

Comment: This has got nothing to do with Rails 5, but rather it is a consequence of upgrading from `jquery-ui v5.x --> 6.0`. The offending line has changed from `require jquery-ui/datepicker` to `require jquery-ui/widgets/datepicker`.

Comment: if using sass, need to put ```@import 'jquery-ui/datepicker';```

Comment: @TomLord is right. You can look into the gem and see how there's a `widgets` subdirectory in that version of jquery-ui. I'm using rails 4 and the same. Refer to [readme](https://github.com/jquery-ui-rails/jquery-ui-rails#require-specific-modules)

Comment: Also worth emphasizing for tired dolts like me that for `jquery-ui-rails` 6.0 users, it's `//=require jquery-ui/widgets/whatever` in `application.js` ... but `/widgets` does not need to be added in `application.css`. (The answer above is correct, just emphasizing it because I totally missed it initially.)

Answer (score 8):

adds 'jquery-ui-rails' on your Gemfile, and use a hyphen instead of a point to require jquery-ui

```
//= require jquery-ui
```

or downgrade the jquery-ui gem version

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 4.2.1'
```

Comment: This is also a good temporary fix for ActiveAdmin for the jquery-ui-rails 5.0 incompatibility until the pull requests are implemented. https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/3250

Answer (score 5):

Downgrading from jquery-ui-rails 5.0.0 to 4.2.1 fixed it for me.

Comment: File names have changed in jquery-ui-rails 5 - use `//= require jquery-ui/all` instead

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to this: I had the same issue, I finally solved it by placing `//= require turbolinks` before the jquery requirements in `application.js`:

```
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```